# Why can't the Python interpreter find the opencv installed in the virtual environment?

Tags: python, opencv, terminal, anaconda

My python version in my virtual environment is 3.9.18.
This is the code running on the terminal，OEM is the name of my virtual environment.

```
(base) PS F:\OEM-Fewshot-Challenge\OEM-Fewshot-Challenge\src> conda activate OEM
(OEM) PS F:\OEM-Fewshot-Challenge\OEM-Fewshot-Challenge\src> py test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\OEM-Fewshot-Challenge\OEM-Fewshot-Challenge\src\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I'm pretty sure I had installed the opencv library in my virtual environment.I check it again and run the test.py but the error still remain.

```
(OEM) PS F:\OEM-Fewshot-Challenge\OEM-Fewshot-Challenge\src> pip list | findstr opencv
opencv-python               4.6.0.66
```

Comment: And what does `conda list | findstr opencv` show?

Comment: Try to check with `where py` from the prompt that you are actually calling the right python

Comment: You're using old Python version.  try this: py -m pip install opencv-contrib-python